# How to use aggregate window function on varchar() datavalues?

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I was writing a query on a dataset and made this table as a CTE (t3)
(DDL and DML statements for this table t3 are given below)

| games | regions | gold | silver | bronze | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1896 Summer | Greece | 2 | 4 | 4 | 10 |
| 1896 Summer | UK | 3 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1896 Summer | Switzerland | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1896 Summer | USA | 8 | 4 | 1 | 13 |
| 1896 Summer | Germany | 7 | 1 | 0 | 8 |
| 1896 Summer | France | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 1896 Summer | Hungary | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1896 Summer | Australia | 2 | 0 | 1 | 3 |

Notes: DDL and DML statements for t3:

DDL statement:
`create table t3 (games varchar(20), regions varchar(20), gold int, silver int, bronze int, total int);`

and DML statements are:

```
insert into t3 values ('1896 Summer', 'Greece', 2, 4, 4, 10);
insert into t3 values ('1896 Summer', 'UK', 3, 1, 1, 5);
insert into t3 values ('1896 Summer', 'Switzerland', 0, 0, 0, 0);
insert into t3 values ('1896 Summer', 'USA', 8, 4, 1, 13);
insert into t3 values ('1896 Summer', 'Germany', 7, 1, 0, 8);
insert into t3 values ('1896 Summer', 'France', 1, 2, 1, 4);
insert into t3 values ('1896 Summer', 'Hungary', 0, 1, 0, 1);
insert into t3 values ('1896 Summer', 'Australia', 2, 0, 1, 3);
```

For this, I have written a query:

```
select distinct games, 
       concat(max(regions) over (partition by games order by gold desc), "-", max(gold) over(partition by games)) as gold_count,
       concat(max(regions) over (partition by games order by silver desc, regions), "-", max(silver) over(partition by games)) as silver_count,
       concat(max(regions) over (partition by games order by bronze desc, regions), "-", max(bronze) over(partition by games)) as bronze_count,
       concat(max(regions) over (partition by games order by total desc), "-", max(total) over(partition by games)) as total
from t3;
```

From this query I am getting this result

| games | gold_count | silver_count | bronze_count | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1896 Summer | USA-8 | Greece-4 | Greece-4 | USA-13 |
| 1896 Summer | USA-8 | USA-4 | Greece-4 | USA-13 |
| 1896 Summer | USA-8 | USA-4 | UK-4 | USA-13 |
| 1896 Summer | USA-8 | USA-4 | USA-4 | USA-13 |

How can I get the results like this:

| games | gold_count | silver_count | bronze_count | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1896 Summer | USA-8 | Greece-4 | Greece-4 | USA-13 |
| 1896 Summer | USA-8 | USA-4 | Greece-4 | USA-13 |

or like this:

| games | gold_count | silver_count | bronze_count | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1896 Summer | USA-8 | Greece-4 & USA-4 | Greece-4 | USA-13 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each games, you want to display the top regions for each type of medal (gold, silver, bronze) and overall, with respect to ties.

One option ranks regions for each type of medal with `rank()`, then pivots with conditional aggregation:

```
select games, 
    group_concat( case when rn_gold   = 1 then concat(regions, '-', gold  ) end separator ' & ') as gold_count,
    group_concat( case when rn_silver = 1 then concat(regions, '-', silver) end separator ' & ') as silver_count,
    group_concat( case when rn_bronze = 1 then concat(regions, '-', bronze) end separator ' & ') as bronze_count,
    group_concat( case when rn_total  = 1 then concat(regions, '-', total ) end separator ' & ') as total_count
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over(partition by games order by gold   desc) rn_gold,
        rank() over(partition by games order by silver desc) rn_silver,
        rank() over(partition by games order by bronze desc) rn_bronze,
        rank() over(partition by games order by total  desc) rn_total
    from t3 t
) t
group by games
```

Which, for your sample data, yields:

| games | gold_count | silver_count | bronze_count | total_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1896 Summer | USA-8 | USA-4 & Greece-4 | Greece-4 | USA-13 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AguvGKhF)

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. @GMB Could you please explain why am I getting four distinct rows? I expected only one distinct row because max(regions) over (partition by games order by silver desc, regions should give me only Greece NOT USA and max(regions) over (partition by games order by bronze desc, regions should give me only Greece NOT UK and USA. Could you please explain the execution of my query? –